# Как вывести свойство детального описания из определенного товара на страницу bitrix?

Tags: html, битрикс

Вот [сайт](http://www.dis-com.ru):
Есть несколько услуг, предлагаемых компанией. В детальном описании услуги есть свойство "*Стоимость*" в котором содержится `html`
[текст](http://www.dis-com.ru/services/arm-pc.html).

Хочу вывести это свойство от всех услуг на странице "*Цены*".
Думал сделать вывод "*элемента каталога детально*", но никак не разберусь с ссылками. Как указать конкретный товар, детальную информацию которого необходимо вывести?
В идеале бы сделать так, чтобы на страницу выводились сразу все имеющиеся товары(услуги) в форме детального просмотра с показом только одного свойства.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте компонент `newslist` и в нём выберите нужные для вывода свойства.